# What library can i use to parse a Schedule String in Java

Tags: java, time, schedule

I am currently writing a program in Java where I have to parse User Input like "every 4 hours" "every day 6:00" or something like that and turn that into an interval.

The only thing I found was the Google Docs for Cloud Cronjobs https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/configyaml/cron#Java_app_yaml_The_schedule_format

Can someone tell me about some library that could achieve this?

EDIT:

I found a ruby library that can do this: https://github.com/yb66/tickle
Is there any Java Implementation of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to take some parts from Rubys Tickle and Chronic and write it myself.

If anyone ever needs this, feel free to contact me

Answer (score 1):

Try JChronic which is a java implementation of Ruby Chronic:

https://github.com/samtingleff/jchronic

This gives allows you to convert things like `next tuesday` into real dates.

Comment: I have looked at the ruby chronic docs, and it seems it's quite good for parsing a string into a date, but that's still not what I want.
I want to parse an interval string like in the link i posted.

Comment: I think you'd need to combine something like chronic with a real scheduler for that e.g Quartz